# Get Registry Binary Value Power Shell

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to get a registry value I tried using Get-ItemProperty -Pame -Name, but it gives me System.Byte[] instead of the value of the value itself, how can I get the hex value?

Comment: What did you expect to get from a **binary** value?

Comment: tbh i expected to get System.Byte[] but idk how to get all the array values in 1 variable @Theo

Comment: `$value = Get-ItemProperty ...` ?

Comment: this gives me System.Byte[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are getting a `Byte[]` array from the registry and want to convert that to a Hex string, correct?

You can convert a byte array like this:

```
$hex = ($value | ForEach-Object { '{0:X2}' -f $_ }) -join ''
```

or use:

```
$hex = ([System.BitConverter]::ToString([byte[]]$value)).Replace('-','')
```

where `$value` is the byte array you have read from the registry